# Partially matching strings

Tags: php, string-matching

I have two variables of type `string` with the following structure:

```
echo $var_1;
"words" : [ "word A", "word B", "word C", "word D" ],

echo $var_2;
"words" : [ "word B", "word D", "word G", ],
```

The strings can contain any number of words, and there is no rule for the structure of the word. What I am trying to do is to write a conditional statement based on whether there is one or more exactly matching word between the two variables. In the example above there are two matches: `"word B"` and `"word D"`. I am after something along these lines:

```
if ($matches > 0) {//some code}
```

Any ideas on how `$matches` could be defined?

Comment: These are values from json? If yes - decode them to array and do `array_intersect`.

Comment: If the type of the variables is string, does it matter if they were obtained from a json or could I just pretend it's json?

Comment: Where did the strings come from? Do they look exactly like that? Then it's not valid json either. If you could parse the strings, giving you an array of the words, it would be easy to solve. But since it seem to be some custom (inconsistent) format, it's gonna be trickier. If you can control the format of the strings, I would start there.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson They come from a larger json. All I have done is two subset it, e.g. `$var_1 = $json_1[2];`. And then this above is what I get when I run `echo $var_1;`.

Comment: I don't know what `$json_1[2]` will give you since I have no idea what `$json_1` contains. However, the strings you posted in your question are not valid json. Does `$json_1` contain a proper array with data or does it contain stringified json? And where does it come from?

Comment: Sorry I think I am confusing you and myself. The source is a curl execution getting a result from an api call that returns json. So `$json_1`comes from a statement like `exec('curl...', $json_1);`. And then I define `$var_1` as described above. And `echo gettype($json_1);`returns `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

you can matched these elements with code like

```
$v1 = array( "word A", "word B", "word C", "word D" );
$v2 = array( "word B", "word D", "word G");

echo json_encode($v1);
echo json_encode($v2);

foreach($v1 as $va)
{
    foreach($v2 as $vb)
    {
        if(strpos($va,$vb) !== false)
        {
            echo "Matched".$va;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I think this is not really what I'm after as I have many variables to match in reality. It's not really an option to define each array manually.

Comment: So, how would you get the words as arrays to start with, since the OP get's them as strings, not arrays?

Comment: but the variables you showing in your ques.. are not strings & not correct json either
i am just showing an example how to matching strings or elements